# Unwrapping function calls in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, algorithmic-trading

I am having trouble understanding and rewriting (so it is clearer) what is going on on **lines 120 - 123** of the file **trading_bot_cf.py** located at: [trading_bot_cf.py file](https://github.com/robsalgado/personal_data_science_projects/blob/master/trading_bot/trading_bot_cf.py)

```
        df['momentum'] = df.groupby('symbol')['close'].rolling(
            momentum_window,
            min_periods=minimum_momentum
            ).apply(momentum_score).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

What is the order in which these functions are called? How can I rewrite these lines as separate sequential function calls? I don't understand how the function calls relate to each other. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: These are chained function calls, where one function returns an object (or `self`) which has functions that can be called and so on. So in principle you could create code which is like: `b = a(); c = b(); d = c()` instead of `d = a().b().c()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I realize they're chained function calls, I want to unchain them but I don't know how. Everything I've been trying has resulted in some kind of error. Can you show me how to unchain these function calls?

Comment: Perhaps your question should have featured one of these attempts along with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `dataframe`, but since it is python, then this line:

```
df['momentum'] = df.groupby('symbol')['close'].rolling(momentum_window, min_periods=minimum_momentum).apply(momentum_score).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Should be able to be split into multiple lines by creating references at each function return:

```
groupby = df.groupby('symbol')['close']
rolling = groupby.rolling(momentum_window, min_periods=minimum_momentum)
apply = rolling.apply(momentum_score)
df['momentum'] = apply.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```